# Only run map once, ramda js

Tags: ramda.js

```
const arr = [{
  _id: 'z11231',
  _typename: 'items'
  id: '123',
  comment: null,
  title: 'hello'
}, {
  _id: 'z11231',
  _typename: 'items'
  id: 'qqq',
  comment: 'test',
  title: 'abc'
}]
```

Wanted output:

```
[['123', null, 'hello'], ['qqq', 'test', 'abc']];

export const convertObjectsWithValues = R.map(R.values);

export const removeMongoIdAndGraphqlTypeName = R.map(R.omit(['_id', '__typename']));

export const getExcelRows = R.pipe(removeMongoIdAndGraphqlTypeName, convertObjectsWithValues);
```

Problem here is I'm running two separate maps. It's to slow. Can I combine this in a way where only one map is executed. And still keep it clean in three seperate functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `R.map` with `R.props` to state which properties you want in the order that you want them. This will always maintain the correct order, unlike. `R.values`, which is constrained by the way [JS orders keys](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"z11231","_typename":"items","id":"123","comment":null,"title":"hello"},{"_id":"z11231","_typename":"items","id":"qqq","comment":"test","title":"abc"}]

const getExcelRows = keys => R.map(R.props(keys))

const result = getExcelRows(['id', 'comment', 'title'])(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need a resuable function. Don't want to specify what keys I want.

Comment: To make it reusable, you can extract the keys to parameter, and state them when you use the function. If your only wish in life is to remove the GQL and Mongo keys, sanitize the data when you get it, and not when you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious to see whether you've actually tested that it's too slow.  The Knuth quote always seems *a propos*: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

But if you've tested, and if multiple iterations are an actual bottleneck in your application, then the [composition law of Functors](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/#functor) should help.  In Ramda terms this  law states that

```
compose ( map (f), map (g) ) ≍ map (compose (f, g) )
```

and of course similarly that

```
pipe ( map (g), map (f) ) ≍ map (pipe (g, f) )
```

That means that you can rewrite your function like this:

```js
const getExcelRows = map (pipe (omit ( ['_id', '_typename'] ), values ))

const arr = [
  {_id: 'z11231', _typename: 'items', id: '123', comment: null, title: 'hello'},
  {_id: 'z11231', _typename: 'items', id: 'qqq', comment: 'test', title: 'abc'}
]

console .log (
  getExcelRows (arr)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script> <script>
const {map, pipe, omit, values} = R                                            </script>
```

Comment: I actually haven't tested on large datasets yet. Just assumed it must be slower to iterate several times on array with +100k items? Are you saying it dosen't matter with ramda?

Comment: @Joe: Ramda is not going to do anything to magically change how many times you iterate -- except that there is some help from transducers.  The point I was making is that unless you test, you really don't know what bits of code are a bottleneck in your system.  Optimizing the wrong ones gains you almost nothing but makes your code harder to maintain.  This isn't a license to be totally stupid about performance choices, but in most cases, I wouldn't make it a high priority unless you've demonstrated that there is a problem.